# Only one file being uploaded using multiple file uploader

Tags: php

The following PHP file script uploads only one file although its supposed to send multiple files. Can't understand where it breaks. Tried using `foreach` but to no avail.

I did a `var_dump` and they show the correct number of files being sent.

**HTML**

```
<form id="fileupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploadfile[]" multiple id="uploadfile" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';

############ Edit settings ##############
$UploadDirectory    = './storage/';
#########################################


if(!isset($_FILES["uploadfile"])) {
    die('Something wrong with upload! Is "upload_max_filesize" set correctly?');
}

//check if this is an ajax request
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])){
    die();
}


// Total number of files to be uploaded
$total_files = count($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);

//check if there is at least 1 file
if($total_files < 1) {
    die();
}


for($i=0; $i<$total_files; $i++) {
    //Is file size is less than allowed size.
    if ($_FILES["uploadfile"]["size"][$i] > 29000000) {
        die("File size is too big!");
    }

    $allowedTypes = array('gif', 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'pdf', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'doc', 'docx', 'ppt', 'pptx', 'mp3', 'mp4', 'rar', 'zip', 'txt');

    $FileNameFull       = strtolower($_FILES['uploadfile']['name'][$i]);
    $FileNameShort      = pathinfo($FileNameFull, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $FileExt            = pathinfo($FileNameFull, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(!in_array($FileExt, $allowedTypes)) {
        die('Unsupported File format!');
    }

    $FileCode      = rand(0, 9999999999); //Random number to be used to rename actual filename
    $NewFileName        = $FileCode.'.'.$FileExt; //new file name

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $UploadDirectory.$NewFileName )) {
        // Save the file details to database
        //$query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO uploads(file_name, file_code, file_ext, timestamps) VALUES (:file_name, :file_code, :file_ext, :timestamps)");
        /*$query->execute(array(
            ":file_name" => $FileNameShort,
            ":file_code" => $FileCode,
            ":file_ext" => $FileExt,
            ":timestamps" => round(microtime(true) * 1000)
        ));*/

        die('Success! File Uploaded.');
    }
    else{
        die('error uploading File!');
    }

}
```

Comment: it is good to post HTML as well.

Comment: For me it stopped at `!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])`, but I haven't tried with Ajax. Note that `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` would not be always set. Not all JS frameworks send such an information.

Comment: Also, prevent to using function `die()` a lot. At least, send some information, so you know where it stopped. And in the `for` loop, do not use `die()` when upload is successfull, because it will upload only one file, then script ends and other files will not be processed.

Comment: Aah! I got my problem. It's the `die('Success! File Uploaded.');` which kill the script after a single upload.

Comment: Apply my code and check all image is in the loop or not then apply your changes.

Comment: @debute, Yes got a bit late typing out the area which caused the problem. Missed it before posting the question. By the way, if any changes can be made to improve the code, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Noman, your code worked just fine.

Comment: @Ayan Accept the answer if it solves your purpose and close this question. Thanks!

Comment: @Noman, sure I would do that. But before that you need to state about the `die()` statement in your answer.

Comment: @Ayan Sure! Kindly check. Thank!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well i will give you a small example:

**HTML:**

```
<input name="uploadfile[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

**PHP:**

```
$totalImage = count($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);

for($i=0; $i<$totalImage; $i++) {
  $temporaryPathOfImage = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'][$i];

  if ($temporaryPathOfImage != ""){
    $dirPath = "./storage/" . $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'][$i];

    if(move_uploaded_file($temporaryPathOfImage, $dirPath)) {
      //Code Here
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem:**

```
die('Success! File Uploaded.');
```

Remove this line so you will get all images in that loop.